# Passing variables between functions in c with out using global variables

Tags: c

I am trying to print the value of a local variable inside of main, from another function without using global variables. What would be the best way to do so?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function1();

int main(void) {
  int hello=10;
  printf(function1());
}

int function1(int ip){
  printf("hello%d",ip); 
}
```

I am expecting the `10` to be printed next to the `"hello"` but instead get a 0.

Comment: You didn't pass a value to `function1`.

Comment: You forgot to return a value from function1().

Comment: `printf(printf(...))` really doesn't make any sense. Are you thinking of `printf()` operating on a buffer populated by `sprintf`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the function passing the value (or variable) required.

```
int function1(int);

int main(void) 
{
  int hello=10;
  function1(hello);
  function1(130);
}

int function1(int ip)
{
  return printf("hello - %d\n",ip); 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/97o3dPWzj

Answer (score 2):

change

```
int function1();
```

to

```
int function1(int);
```

and

```
 printf(function1());
```

to

```
 function1(hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am expecting the 10 to be printed next to the "hello" but instead get a 0."*

There are already examples of working versions of your code in the other answers, but little is said in the way of explanation. I will try to do that here, and offer some general suggestions.

Although your code compiles, it does so with warnings and when run, produces run-time errors.  The information resulting from both of these, if heeded would likely provide a guide to addressing most of your issues. (If using `GCC` for example, you can set warnings to `-Wall`). To illustrate, here is an image showing line numbers and the warning that correspond with them on my system (not GCC, but warning are turned on)

[image]

Build warnings:
[image]
And finally, run-time error:
[image]

From these you can begin to derive some of the following observations (others listed are my own.)

- The signature of a function prototype must match its implementation. (for function1, they do not)
- If the prototype of a function is non-void, then it should return a value.
- If a function returns a value, its return value should not be ignored.
- The warning of an unused variable pointed out that you probably intended to use it as an argument here: `function1()`

See comments below for other clarifications:

```
int function1();//this prototype is incomplete, and is inconsistent
                //with the signature of its implementation

int main(void) {
  int hello=10;
  printf(function1());//because function1 is not returning a value, your code outputs a 0
                      //Function1 prototype requires it to pass an argument
  // non-void function should return a value here
}

int function1(int ip){//signature of this implementation disagrees with its prototype
                      //because there is no value passed, ip can be any value 
  printf("hello%d",ip); 
  // non-void function should return a value here
}
```